# Colors in RegionPlot legend

Tags: graphics, plotting

I'm trying to put a common legend for two-row RegionPlot. However, I haven't been able to get the colors in the legend right:

```
ra = RegionPlot[{y >= x^2 - 4 , y >= x^2 - 4 && y <= 0 }, {x, -10, 
   10}, {y, -10, +10}]

rb = RegionPlot[{y >= x^2 - 16 , y >= x^2 - 16 && y <= 0 }, {x, -20, 
20}, {y, -20, +20}]

Legended[GraphicsRow[{ra, rb}, Spacings -> Scaled[0.4], 
  Epilog -> Inset["Plot Title", Scaled[{0.5, 0.95}]]], 
 SwatchLegend[{Blue, Orange}, {"label1", "label2"}]]


Legended[GraphicsRow[{ra, rb}, Spacings -> Scaled[0.4], 
  Epilog -> Inset["Plot Title", Scaled[{0.5, 0.95}]]], 
 SwatchLegend[{LightBlue, LightOrange}, {"label1", "label2"}]]
```

I've also tried to change the colors of the regions. However, as far as I could tell, the declared color applied to the boundaries; the interior was a shade lighter, something I couldn't reproduce in the legend. Any ideas on how to address the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one?

```
ra = RegionPlot[{y >= x^2 - 4, y >= x^2 - 4 && y <= 0}, {x, -10, 
        10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange}, 
       BoundaryStyle -> None];
    rb = RegionPlot[{y >= x^2 - 16, y >= x^2 - 4 && y <= 0}, {x, -10, 
        10}, {y, -18, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange}, 
       BoundaryStyle -> None];
    Legended[Labeled[Multicolumn[{ra, rb}], 
      Style["Plot Title", 15, Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], Top], 
     SwatchLegend[{Blue, Orange}, {"label1", "label2"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: It did work! Now, although my application is much more convoluted, this MWE captures the fact that each region is a subset of another. Thus, anyone interested in using this approach should start ``RegionPlot`` from the largest set, and then proceed all the way towards the smallest. The order matters here.